# Receiving "System.StringException: Invalid id:" error even though the String that is being created checks for the scenario

Tags: string, isblank

For the following String creation within a trigger, I'm checking to see if the field is blank. If not, then it should use that field's value as the correct string, else, it should remain blank.

```
String sitenprodcomb = (String.isNotBlank(line.Site__c) ? line.Site__c : '') + String.valueof(line.ProductId__c);
```

However, I'm getting the String exception described in the title when I try to adjust the status of an object using this trigger, I get the error described in the title.

[image]

Line 272 simply invokes the function that houses this string. The data is being moved into this function correctly. What alternatives do you suggest for setting this String to the correct value?

Comment: Are you expecting `sitenprodcomb` to be an ID....I don't see how it can ever be if `Site__c` is not blank?

Comment: `sitenprodcomb` is a concatenated String that contains the Site Id and the Product Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String conditional output was replaced with an if/else block. That fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're assigning an empty string to a variable of type Id. A null value is fine for an Id, but an empty string isn't.

The problem is not in the line you posted.

Comment: Could you share why an empty string is invalid?

Comment: @KaiTribble, empty strings can't be assigned to a field of type ID (like a lookup field). You have to use `null`

Comment: You should really consider Id a separate data type. You can assign values to it like you would to a String variable, but only in the valid formats of an Id. Which means it has to have 15 or 18 characters, and not all characters are valid. I don't know what exactly the restrictions are, but an empty string simply isn't a valid Id.